# Opening "save as..." dialog from :ex command

Tags: vim

When I "save as..." a file from the menu, I get the usual windows "save as..." dialog, but when I save using the :sav command, I can only use vim file name completion. Is there a way to open the "save as..." dialog using an ex command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
:browse saveas
```

or, for short

```
:bro sav
```

Comment: I just :helped :browser, useful!

Thanks :bro

Comment: :bro sav might be the best vim command ever. Thanks for helping me, and making me laugh.